# Proportion of pairs of consecutive coin-flips that are $HH$

Tags: probability

Say I flip a coin $n+1$ times. This gives me $n$ pairs of consecutive coin-flips.

(a) What is the expected proportion of these consecutive coin-flips that are $HH$?

(b) What is the expected proportion that are $HT$?

(E.g. I flip a coin $4$ times and get $HTTH$. This gives me $3$ pairs of consecutive coin-flips, namely $HT$, $TT$, and $TH$. On this particular trial, I get $0/3$ of $HH$ and $1/3$ of $HT$.)

By simulation I think the answers are both $1/4$, but I'm not sure how to prove this. And if my guess is correct, here's an additional question:

(c) What is the intuition for why the above two answers are the same, even though the expected wait time to get $HH$ is 6 flips while the expected wait time to get $HT$ is 4 flips?

Comment: Re (c), note that once HH appeared once, it reappears sooner than HT does after it appeared once, since HH is already half realized while to get a new HT one has to restart from scratch. Thus, a later first appearance is compensated by some faster next appearances, and vice versa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a random pair, its either HH, TH, HT or TT, assign a 1 if its HH.
We are looking for the expected value of the sum $E(pair_1+pair_2...)$ over all consecutive pairs (divided by $n+1$). But this is just $E(pair_1)+E(pair_2)$+.. even if they are not independent.

Comment: This is referred to as "linearity of independence" (in case you want to search and read more about it).

Comment: Please [format](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) your post in order to improve readability.